# VSTS SpecFlowPlus: not compatible with your current operating system 'Windows(X86)'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, specflow

On my VSTS Server the **SpecFlowPlus task** fails with the following error:

> A supported task execution handler was not found. The task does not carry an implementation that is compatible with your current
>   operating system 'Windows(X86)'. Contact the task author for more
>   details.

## Question:

1. How can I get the SpecFlowPlus Task running?
2. Or how can I make sure the VSTest Task is executing in x84 mode?

## Details:

1. I realized that "Any CPU" was set as plattform so I changed all placece to x86.

The **VSBuild Tasks** seems to be okay and puts the compiled artifacts into a x86 folder:

[image]

2. The **VSTest Task** starts in x64 mode and fails silently with the following error message:

[image]

(excerpt from azure-pipeline.yml)

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**/*.sln'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:Platform=x86 /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: 'x86'
    configuration: 'Release'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\Calculator.Spec.dll
      !**\obj\**
    platform: 'x86'
    configuration: 'Release'

- task: SpecFlowPlus@0
  inputs:
    projectFilePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    projectLanguage: 'en'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error occurred because the SpecFlowPlus Task was excuted on a x84 machine. The task version of VSbuild and VStest is not what caused the error.

If you look closely at the SpecFlowPlus Task excution log. The task execution handler is actually the Generate.ps1 script, and the error indicated that it didnot support x84 platform. I tried running Generate.ps1 locally on x86 mode and x64 mode powershell, it indeed failed out on x86 mode.

You can try running your pipeline on an x64 platform agent and see how it will go.

```
Preparing task execution handler.
Executing the powershell script: C:\agent-mic\_work\_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.3.6/Generate.ps1
```

Comment: You are right. Using a x64 agent does the trick. It seems the SpecFlowPlus Task can only be executed with a x64 agent. The information provided on the specflow.org website leads to confusion: "...define test targets for your various environments (x86/x64, multiple browsers) to execute them on all platforms." https://image.prntscr.com/image/voh1yJXlR8Wt7NMXVYb8Ew.png Thanks for your support.